# Python tkinter limit entry input

Tags: python, tkinter, limit, tkinter-entry

How do I limit the input on a Entry to only 4 characters

```
from tkinter import *
window = Tk()

display = Entry(window)
display.grid()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by running a trace on the attribute `textvariable` of the `entry` widget. Whenever this variable is updated you will need to set the variable to it's own value up to the 4th character.

See below:

```
from tkinter import *

class App:
    def __init__(self, root):
        self.root = root
        self.sv = StringVar()
        self.entry = Entry(root, textvariable = self.sv)
        self.entry.pack()
        self.sv.trace("w", lambda name, index, mode, sv=self.sv: self.callback(self.sv))
    def callback(self, sv):
        self.sv.set(self.sv.get()[:4])

root = Tk()
App(root)
root.mainloop()
```